# Could not convert string to float: Python code for a pH meter

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, chemistry

I'm new to coding and am attempting to build a pH meter with pre-written code for the GUI. I've double checked all connections in my instrument, but the python code is the last thing crashing. When I try and run the instrument, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\livst\sensors.py", line 353, in updateFigs
    self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split()] # split data to 
    float numbers
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\livst\sensors.py", line 353, in <listcomp>
    self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split()] # split data to 
   float numbers
             ^^^^^^^^^^
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'Read'
```

After some reading, I attempted to decode the string using `text.decode("utf-8")` and by using `text.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")`.

When I use these commands, I get the same error with different text in the ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\livst\sensors.py", line 353, in updateFigs
    self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split()] # split data to float numbers
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\livst\sensors.py", line 353, in <listcomp>
    self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split()] # split data to float numbers
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'H\xf4Read'
```

This is the portion of code it is referring to in the error:

```
def updateFigs(self):
        line = self.ser.readline() # read data from serial port, one line at a time
        self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split()] # split data to float numbers
        # the data read from the serial port should be 4 float numbers, otherwise neglect it.
        # the 4 float numbers are temperaure, humidity, voltage at reference electrode,
        # and voltage at pH electrode, respectively.
        line.decode("utf-8")
        if(len(self.data) == 4):
            self.temp_lcd.display(self.data[0])
            self.temp_plot.y = np.append(self.temp_plot.y, float(self.data[0]))
            self.temp_plot.y = np.delete(self.temp_plot.y, 0)
            self.temp_plot.li.set_ydata(self.temp_plot.y)
            self.temp_plot.axes.set_ylim(min(self.temp_plot.y)-1, max(self.temp_plot.y)+1)
            self.temp_plot.draw()
```

The GUI opens, but I can't collect data yet. How can I resolve this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with encoding. You can see in the error that you're trying to turn the word "Read" into a decimal number. That will not work. There is not enough info in your question to help you

Comment: You need to get into the habit of debugging. What do you get if you use `print(line)` before the line that throws the error?

Comment: You need to look further back into the code to find why the data from the serial port is not in the form of lines of strings representing float numbers.

Comment: The best would be if you provide an example output from the serial connection. Is the serial device something that you developed yourself? If not there has to be documentation about this interface.

Comment: I'm using an Arduino Nano board connected via USB, and the program for it is written in Sketch. I can go back through that code and see if there is an error there not outputting the expected 4 numerical values. I am a super beginner + am trying to learn as much as possible from this. the sketch code was not throwing any errors at time of upload to board. I am trying some debugging methods now

Comment: In your code you are splitting `line` into floats, and _then_ decoding `line` as UTF-8. I wonder if these should be the other way around?

Comment: To debug you could add `self.data = []` (comment the existing line out), and then as roganjosh says, print what `line` is. I assume you call this repeatedly. The string "read" appears to be sensible data (presumably fetched from the serial interface) so maybe you need to test the format of each line before trying to convert it (i.e. only convert lines to floats where that makes sense).

Answer (score -3):

Check *val* before parsing.

```py
self.data = [float(val) for val in line.split() if val.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: `"1.23".isnumeric()`. Not only is this speculative, it clearly won't work